# Could you help me listen to what this guy is saying?

Tags: listening

I linked the video   [starts at 30secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g8oeVFPwDw&feature=youtu.be)
I've found the script of this episode.
The script says

> "It's amazing. I mean, I really, really, seriously appreciate that."

That's what Louis says to Mike.
But to me, it doesn't sound like 'really, really'.
I can't even catch the words.
It sounds like mumbling and he has a lower voice.
 Not clear to me. (I'm an English learner.)
Is he really saying " I really really seriously appreciate that."?

Comment: Not your fault, but that video is blocked in the US.  Sorry I can't help.  FWIW, "_really, really"_ fits perfectly in the context you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I mean, I really, really, seriously appreciate that."

Yes this matches the audio.

It looks like he's trying to hold a smile at the same time, and not opening his mouth a lot, which makes it hard to lip-read.